# How to pass an command argument like $(date +"%Y") in bash through java?

Tags: java, bash, parameters, scripting

I know we can pass argument in bash through the Runtime in java. I have a special case, I want to pass arguments like $(date +"%Y""%m") as a parameter in the bash which will in turn be computed and stored in a variable in bash. Consider the following java code:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "/user/username/test.sh", "firstparameter", "date +%Y", "folder_$(date +%Y)";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

The above command runs the shell script test.sh. My script goes as follows:

```
first=$1
year=`$2`
foldername=`$3`

echo $first
echo $year
echo $foldername
```

I have included backticks on my bash code so that the argument passed through the java program can be executed first. The output of the command will be:

```
firstparameter
2020
$(date: not found
```

I want the bash to have the foldername as folder_2020. How can we achieve this? I tried many times but could not succeed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, in your code, you are running your script as _sh_, not _bash_.

Comment: Hi @user1934428 , I did not understand your question. I am new to bash if you could explain a little bit that would be great.

Comment: You are setting the first argument of cmd to 'sh', which means that your script is run by 'sh'. If you would set the first argument to 'foofoo', the script would be run by 'foofoo'. If you want to run it by bash, you have to set the first argument to 'bash'.

Comment: Thank you @user1934428.. I understood your question.... It was suppose to be a bash script ..I will modify my question and change the first parameter to bash ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the last argument:

```
"folder_$(date +%Y)"
```

with

```
"date +folder_%Y"
```

Making the argument into a valid command ensuress that it will execute as intended in the shell script.

---

Alternatively you can leave your last argument as is, and modify your shell script instead.

Replace this variable assignment:

```
foldername=`$3`
```

with this:

```
eval "foldername=\"$3\""
```

The `eval` call will take care of performing any command substitution that is embedded in `$3`.

Comment: Thank you so much @rtx13. I was scratching my head for the last two hours for this issue. Really appreciate it. Thank you so much. It worked

Comment: @SaugatDahal You're welcome.  I added an alternative solution which requires changes only to the shell script.